# Render settings for high resolution images for printing scenes with many small geometries

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, settings

I can't get a good output material for further processing in Photoshop
when rendering images for printing in large format from A2 with 300 dpi.
Since I set a high resolution, the files are huge, but the quality is not satisfactory (no sharpness).

These are outdoor scenes with a lot of geometry, such as trees with leaves.
What can I do to make small objects in the background of the scene sharp?

Which render settings in Cycles can you recommend, resolution, number of samples, number of light paths and what other settings do I need to consider?

Does the size of the camera sensor have an effect on the image quality, or what else has an influence on the image quality?

Comment: Reduce Render-Film-Pixel Filter, also make sure you don't have a motion blur or depth of field enabled.

Comment: How many pixels are "A2 with 300 dpi"?

Comment: @Blunder Should be something around 7016 × 4961 pixels.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Box filter gives thes sharpest results, with Blackman-Harris filter the optimum is 1.0? what exactly is happening when i change Blackman-Harris below 1.0? I get better sharpness when I render in higher resolution (800% of 7016 x 4967px) and then reszise the image in Photoshop to A2 format why is that so?